# postgres connection details in django and chef

Tags: django, postgresql, chef-infra

I have a django application that uses a postgres DB.

I have a chef recipe that sets up the postgres DB, including setting up a postgres username/password for the django app to use.

This username/password is then used by the DATABASES settings.py value.

At the moment I have to have the postgres details in both `attributes.rb` **and** in `settings.py`.
How can I have them in just one place?

Options I have currently considered:

1. Having `settings.py` (or part of it) generated by a chef template. That way the details only need to be in the chef recipe.
   The downside of this is that the django app is incomplete unless it is deployed via chef. (This might not be that much of an issue, as even local dev is done with vagrant+chef).
2. Having a known file on the filesystem that `settings.py` checks and loads some values from. This file is generated by chef.
   This is only a little bit better than the first solution. Also it requires some boilerplate code in settings.py to load and parse the file.
3. Have the details in `settings.py` and let chef extract them (somehow).
   This approach is problematic because it muddles with the ordering in the chef recipe (I have to check out my django app, extract the value, use the values to set up postgres, and then start django).
   That itself might not be too bad, but the real issue comes when/if I want to move to a system where passwords aren't in source-controlled files but in something like chef's data-bags.

I've googled quite a bit, but other than various discussions on the layout of `settings.py` and general talk about how to use django and chef, I can't find a nice solution.
Surely someone else has deployed a django app with postgres using chef and come across this before?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [data bag](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_data_bags.html). And as you store a password there, it should be [encrypted data bag](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_data_bags.html). Then you can read data from it in both recipes (postgres and python).

And storing your passwords in attributes also is not a good idea - because they are too exposed.

Comment: I can't see any easy way of accessing the data bag item from python (Other than exporting the data bag to a file on the filesystem, and then having `settings.py` read it). Is that what you mean?

Comment: Recipe should read the data bag, then creates `settings.py` from template passing the read values.